# yum install PHP Error Summary

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum, php

so I'm following  [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) tutorial to install php5 in a red hat 6.5 box and
I have only type one command and is this one below, I just wantend to install the php-gd module.(testing..)
when I try this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-apc php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongo php-sqlite php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml
```

I get this error:

```
    Dependencies Resolved

    =======================================================================================    

    Package           Arch   Version          Repository                             Size
=======================================================================================
Installing:
 php-pecl-apc      x86_64 3.1.9-2.el6      rhel-x86_64-server-6                   96 k
 php-pecl-memcache x86_64 3.0.5-4.el6      rhel-x86_64-server-6                   60 k
 php-pgsql         x86_64 5.3.3-27.el6_5   rhel-x86_64-server-6                   70 k
 php54-mcrypt      x86_64 5.4.27-1.ius.el6 rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius     25 k
 php54-mysqlnd     x86_64 5.4.27-1.ius.el6 rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius    238 k
 php54-pecl-memcached
                   x86_64 2.2.0-1.ius.el6  rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius     43 k
 php54-pecl-mongo  x86_64 1.5.1-1.ius.el6  rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius    151 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libmcrypt         x86_64 2.5.7-5.el6      rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-common  99 k
 libmemcached10    x86_64 1.0.16-1.ius.el6 rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius    154 k
 libtool-ltdl      x86_64 2.2.6-15.5.el6   rhel-x86_64-server-6                   44 k
 php54-common      x86_64 5.4.27-1.ius.el6 rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius    903 k
 php54-pdo         x86_64 5.4.27-1.ius.el6 rackspace-rhel-x86_64-server-6-ius     95 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================
Install      12 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.9 M
Installed size: 0  
Is this ok [y/N]: Y
Downloading Packages:
(1/12): libmcrypt-2.5.7-5.el6.x86_64.rpm                        |  99 kB     00:00     
(2/12): libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm              | 154 kB     00:00     
(3/12): libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64.rpm                  |  44 kB     00:00     
(4/12): php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64.rpm                     |  96 kB     00:00     
(5/12): php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64.rpm                |  60 kB     00:00     
(6/12): php-pgsql-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64.rpm                     |  70 kB     00:00     
(7/12): php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm                | 903 kB     00:00     
(8/12): php54-mcrypt-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm                |  25 kB     00:00     
(9/12): php54-mysqlnd-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm               | 238 kB     00:00     
(10/12): php54-pdo-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm                  |  95 kB     00:00     
(11/12): php54-pecl-memcached-2.2.0-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm        |  43 kB     00:00     
(12/12): php54-pecl-mongo-1.5.1-1.ius.el6.x86_64.rpm            | 151 kB     00:00     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                  930 kB/s | 1.9 MB     00:02     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/curl.so from install of php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/fileinfo.so from install of php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/json.so from install of php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so from install of php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so from install of php54-common-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so from install of php54-pdo-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so from install of php54-pdo-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so from install of php54-pdo-5.4.27-1.ius.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pdo-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
```

### Error Summary

So I think nothing has happen yet. but I will like to roll back this transaction if possible so theres is no lost link somewhere that can ruin some configuration later on. 
I do have php 5.3.3 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add/install the remi YUM repository configurations before you can enable it. Directions for doing this are available here in this articled titled: [Installing RHEL EPEL Repo on Centos 5.x or 6.x](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x).

General steps for CentOS 6.x:

```
$ wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
$ sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
```

As you stated, nothing has happened given the conflicts you're running into.